# How can I move forward and backward data between to different stateful widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is `count` variable in the first stateful widget, I have passed it to `Setting class`. And, `Setting class` passes it to`SettingStateBuilder`. Then, its value is changed in `incrementing`() in `SettingStateBuilder`. I want the updated value to return back to `HomePageBody` for further work. How can I do that?

The **first** stateful widget is created as follow:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageBody createState() => HomePageBody();
}

class HomePageBody extends State<HomePage> {
   int count=0;
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       ...
       new Setting(count);
   }
}
```

The **second** stateful widget is created as follow:

```
class Setting extends StatefulWidget {
   int count;
   Setting(this.count);

   @override
   SettingStateBuilder createState() => SettingStateBuilder(count);
}

class SettingStateBuilder extends State<Setting> {
   int count;
   SettingStateBuilder(this.count);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container( 
       new Text(count.toString());
       ....
       onPressed: () => setState(() => incrementing(context))),
    );
  }
  incrementing(context) { count += 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `Function` property to the `Settings` widget that will be called when the counter is incremented, and pass that function when you create the widget so in `HomePage` you can update the counter:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageBody createState() => HomePageBody();
}

class HomePageBody extends State<HomePage> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text('Settings'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => Settings(
                        count,
                        (newCount) {
                          setState(
                            () {
                              count = newCount;
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                ),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('$count'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  final int count;
  final Function(int) onCounterChanged;

  Settings(this.count, onCounterChanged);

  @override
  SettingsStateBuilder createState() => SettingsStateBuilder(count);
}

class SettingsStateBuilder extends State<Settings> {
  int count;
  SettingsStateBuilder(this.count);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('$count'),
            MaterialButton(
              child: Text('Increment'),
              onPressed: () => setState(
                    () {
                      increment();
                    },
                  ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  increment() {
    count += 1;
    widget.onCounterChanged(count);

  }
}
```

If you are dealing with a more complex use case I suggest you to read for how to approach state management in Flutter, some resources:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: How can I do this without user interaction,onPressed, in `HomePageBody` ? I just simply called `Setting` in `HomePageBody` without user interaction.

Comment: Instead of just calling Settings(), add the onCounterChanged action when initializing it.